# Additional drivers to ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10

Hi im new at this ubuntu way of life,

i got and install ubuntu 13.10 saucy salamander, i dont know where but get kind of lost in the installing process.

i got a lot of problems getting the music been able to play, movies in the other hand i cant get it right, already done the "Things to do after installing ubuntu" list and didnt work for movies, additionals drivers or codecs needed? where can i find it?

Can someone please help :( im thinking to reinstall everything al over again :|. thank you all in advance for your suggestions :D

Comment: Avinash thank you, already done that days ago.

ubuntu-restricted-extras ya está en su versión más reciente.
0 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 17 no actualizados.

Sorry for spanish, but it says that restricted extras are already installed, but it just wont work, trying again just tells me that gstreamer1.0-libav need to be installed when i hit continue button later tells me forbiden like this:

Failed to fetch http://mirror.tcpdiag.net/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libav/libavutil51_0.8.6-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb 403  Forbidden2ubuntu1 no está instalado

Answer (score 1):

### Starting from a standard Ubuntu **13.10** install, add the following:

Update the system (manually)

**`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`**

**`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`**

---

(Optional) If you need to remote access (to this platform)

**`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`**

---

Add some tools, used below

**`sudo apt-get -y install vim curl build-essential`**

Set to auto-update, for security updates

**`sudo vim /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`**

.. by replacing existing file contents with:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "5";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

Disable 'Guest' login account

**`sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -l false`**

---

(Optional) Add 'Ubuntu Tweak' tools/app

**`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa && sudo apt-get --quiet update`**

**`sudo apt-get -y install ubuntu-tweak`**

---

Load ALL video, audio codecs, etc.

**`curl ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/debian/videolan-apt.asc | sudo apt-key add -`**

**`echo "deb ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libdvdcss.list`**

**`sudo apt-get update`**

Install VLC, Mplayer, and Ubuntu restricted extras

**`sudo apt-get -y install vlc vlc-data vlc-plugin-pulse browser-plugin-vlc`**

**`sudo apt-get -y install mplayer`**

**`sudo apt-get -y install ubuntu-restricted-extras`**

Install full DVD capabilities

**`sudo apt-get -y install libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4`**

**`sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`**

### The should cover most things you needed ..

Comment: i got stuck with the Add some tools, used below step, throws that some dependencies need to be fulfil like installing:

jfcmairena@jfcmairenaLp1:~$ sudo apt-get -y install vim curl build-essential

build-essential:i386 :

gcc:i386 (>= 4:4.4.3) but it will not be installed
g++:i386 (>= 4:4.4.3) but it will not be installed
dpkg-dev:i386 (>= 1.13.5) it's not installable

vim:i386 :
vim-runtime:i386 (= 2:7.4.000-1ubuntu2) it's not installable
libpython2.7:i386 (>= 2.7) but it will not be installed

E: problems can't be corrected, you have retained broken packages.

what should i do at this point?

Comment: The **build-essential** is not actually being used, and you could remove it from that command. I am not sure what the cause was. For recover, start with: **`sudo apt-get -f install`**.

Answer (score 0):

Install all XINE packages and dependencies. Open a terminal and type in this code:

sudo apt-get xine*

Input your user password when prompted, and after you get the list with packages to be installed press 'y' which is YES to finish installing xine. This will add a few extra codecs, and if you want to start xine from the start menu to play your favorite video files you can also install gxine (xine user interface). Code:

sudo apt-get install gxine

Next, you should open Synaptic, type 'vlc' without the quotes in the Search field, and look for some extra packages that can boost VLC player, and also add some extra codecs. If VLC player is not present on your system, you can easily install all the packages, and dependencies in a terminal. Code:

sudo apt-get install vlc*

Don't forget to provide your password and press 'y' again to finish installation.

And finally you can install mplayer and mencoder packages. Type in a terminal:

sudo apt-get install mplayer mencoder

And you're done. I hope you have enough free space on your Linux/Ubuntu partition because all these packages to be installed can use sometimes up to 500-600 MB of your free space or even more depending on your Ubuntu distro.

I forgot to mention that you can also install Audacious player if you want to play your music files at their best. Code:

sudo apt-get install audacious*

You can customize audacious interface to look very similar to how Winamp looks if you go to Audacious preferences menu - View - Interface and choose 'Winamp Classic Interface. Next you can choose a skin for audacious from Interface Preferences. If you want latest version of Audacious, you can find it here: https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8

I am editing this post because I am not allowed to give long replies in a simple comment. Before you get tired of all these errors, and decide to reinstall Ubuntu ( maybe you want to try [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) for a change, and not Ubuntu 13.10) I have some more suggestions for you:

You should look for Software Sources ( Open Update Manager from the main menu, and press Settings button ), and see in there if all is checked under UBUNTU tab, and also if you have the required official keys from Ubuntu developers under the AUTHENTICATION tab. There is a button saying RESTORE DEFAULTS under AUTHENTICATION tab, and you can press it to get back your authentication keys assuming that you did something wrong and changed something in there which prevents you from updating and installing software. But before anything check your Internet connection, and if it is working try to run this code in a terminal and see if it works:

sudo apt-get update

Good luck, and if you can't do anything about it, then you should reinstall Ubuntu, whichever version you prefer, 13.10 or 14.04.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, but once again im sorry for been such a noob with this, when i try to execute this at mi terminal it doesnt work:

sudo apt-get xine*, is that "*" needed?
When i try with: sudo apt-get install gxine i get a lot of 403  Forbidden.
The same with: sudo apt-get install vlc (without the *) what am i doing wrong?

:(

Comment: Yes, "*" the little star at the end of a package' name tells the installer to install the package and ALL the other packages and dependencies needed for the main package to work. If you get those errors with 403 Forbidden it means your Internet connection is not up and running, and this is why you can't install new software. Check your Internet connection, and if you can browse the Internet, and your connection is working then it is definitely a problem with your repositories, the sources from which you can install new software.